# python global None object hint

Tags: python, object, pycharm

I have this:

```
my_object = None


def main():
  global my_object
  my_object = MyObject()
  # do stuff with my_object

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

I would like to take advantage of PyCharm's autocomplete when referencing my_object.
The only way I can figure out how to do this is to initialize it at the top:

```
my_object = MyObject()


def main():
  global my_object
  # do stuff with my_object

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

The problem is that the constructor takes arguments that need to be initiated before calling it.

Any suggestions would be most welcome!

Comment: Maybe if you add a type hint like `my_object: MyObject` outside of the function (instead of assigning `None`, PyCharm would recognize that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate the global name *without* assigning it a value:

```py
my_object: MyObject


def main():
  global my_object
  my_object = MyObject()
  # do stuff with my_object

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

This statically hints that `my_object` is *always* of type `MyObject`. There is no intermediate `None` value/type ever assigned to it.

Be aware that at runtime, the name `my_object` is not defined unless assigned to inside `main`; when giving such an annotation, it is your responsibility to construct the code in such a way that `my_object` is initialised before usage.

Comment: Very nice!  I like this solution because I don't have to import anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be global, and you want it to be initially set to `None`, the variable would be of type `Optional[MyObject]`:

```
from typing import Optional

my_object: Optional[MyObject] = None

def main():
  global my_object
  my_object = MyObject()
  # do stuff with my_object

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Pycharm now successfully autocompletes `my_object`'s attributes. If you were using a stricter linter though (MyPy for example), you would need to do a `if myObject is not None` check first before using `my_object` to ensure that `my_object` isn't `None`, or else you'd get more warnings. Pycharm's linter implementation is really lax though, and doesn't care about `Optional`s potentially containing `None`.